# Bucle while no para

Tags: java

Hola chicos estoy con un programa que muestra una tabla de anmortizacion pero cuando entra en el bucle while no se como parar, lo he intentado volviendo a solicitar datos por teclado o con un if, pero no lo logro. Me podeis echar una mano? de lo que ya hay sobre esto no consigo entenderlo al ser diferentes ejercicios. Os pongo código.

```
public class Ejercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner interes = new Scanner(System.in);
        double acumulado;
        final int PLAZO = 5;
        double introduceInteres;
        
        System.out.println("***********************");
        System.out.println("INTRODUCE INTERES");
        introduceInteres = interes.nextDouble();
        
        if (introduceInteres == 0) {

            System.out.println("**************************");
            System.out.println("YA HEMOS TERMINADO");
        }

        while (introduceInteres != 0) {

            double[][] saldo = new double[6][PLAZO];

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

                saldo[i][0] = 10000;
                acumulado = 10000;

                for (int x = 1; x < PLAZO; x++) {

                    acumulado = acumulado + (acumulado * introduceInteres);

                    saldo[i][x] = acumulado;
                }

                introduceInteres = introduceInteres + 0.01;

            }

            for (int z = 0; z < 6; z++) {

                System.out.println();

                for (int y = 0; y < PLAZO; y++) {

                    System.out.printf("%1.2f", saldo[z][y]);

                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }
            
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo que esperas que hagan por vos... introduceInteres <- nunca baja, con lo cual nunca va a parar.. en que momento debe parar de iterar? seguro te falta una condicion y no es esa que mostras...

Comment: Primero tienes que entender como funciona una condición `while` ya que tu pregunta demuestra que no entiendes la lógica de este.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el bucle `while` no se detendrá ya que el valor del `introduceInteres` solo está siendo incrementado, es decir, la condición `introduceInteres != 0` siempre se cumplirá.

Si lo que deseas es que se esté pidiendo el valor en cada iteración y se detenga cuando el usuario ingrese 0, te sugiero cambiar el bucle while por do while:

```
do{  
    
    System.out.println("***********************");
    System.out.println("INTRODUCE INTERES");
    introduceInteres = interes.nextDouble();

    if (introduceInteres == 0) {
        System.out.println("**************************");
        System.out.println("YA HEMOS TERMINADO");
    }else{
        //demás código a ejecutar
    }

}while( introduceInteres != 0 );
```

Con esto entrará al bucle una primera iteración, posterior a esto pedirá el valor de `introduceInteres` y en caso de ser 0 se detendra, si es distinto a 0 ejecutará los ciclos for y nuevamente entrará a otra iteración.

Comment: Muchas gracias Javier, chicos es que me estaba haciendo un lio sobre donde poner el if, porque el bucle while ya lo habia puesto pero no me iba por el tema del if. Muchas gracias.